# How to declare a variable once in a controller rather than for every ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using MVC4 and I have a question, rather than declaring ViewBag.MenuLevel="twostage"; in EACH ActionResult in my controllers can I declare it ONCE for each controller somehow?  Right now for example I have lets say 40 ActionResults per controller, this seems silly to have to declare a variable that many times - so I am sure I am missing something simple.

I need to be able to consume it in my View somehow to affect presentation.  Thoughts? Models? Kind of new to MVC so be gentle! ;)

Basically I want each section (controller) to display a different background-color on the front-end so I want to print the section/controller to an id in the html so I can control via css.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have to set the ViewBag data each time, that's an unavoidable feature of the architecture. However, you can make it a little cleaner in terms of controller code with an attribute applied to the controller.

```
public class ViewBagAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var controller = filterContext.Controller;

        controller.ViewBag.MenuLevel = "twostage";
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) { }
}
```

If you apply that attribute to the controller, you won't have to explicitly add the ViewBag code for each Action method, as `OnActionExecuting` is called automatically for every Action method.

Comment: And we can also pass parameter to the ViewBagAttribute ... to set different MenuLevels in different controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `BaseController` class in which you define the shared fields and values.  All your specific controllers inherit from the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own controller class and inherit all your controllers from it. Fill the `ViewBag` with the variables you need to pass to all your views in this controller class.

Comment: Ok sounds interesting, so then do I just give the declared variables values within the specific controllers?  Ie. if I set a public string MyVar in the BaseController, do I then in my other controllers somehow give that MyVar value?

Comment: Yes, could be.. You can have a default value and then rewrite it from particular controller or action. Just update the ViewBag from your MyVar setter.